# JEditorPane content type "text/html" line breaks with no paragraph creation

Tags: java, html, swing

When I create a `JEditorPane` with `setContentType("text/html")` and I press enter editing text, a new html paragraph (`<p style="margin-top: 0">`) is created. Is there any way to insert line break tags (`<br>`) instead of that?

Here is the example:

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setTitle("Text Area");

        JEditorPane editor = new JEditorPane();
        editor.setContentType("text/html");

        Box pane = Box.createVerticalBox();

        pane.add(editor);
        frame.add(pane);

        frame.setSize(500, 500);

        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println(editor.getText());
                e.getWindow().dispose();
            }
        });

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This is the outpup of a written text:

```html
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <p style="margin-top: 0">
      First line
    </p>
    <p style="margin-top: 0">
      This is a new line
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is what I would like to have:

```html
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <p style="margin-top: 0">
      First line<br>
      This is a new line
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The usual way for editors to create a `<br>` is by using [shift]+[enter]. Try that instead.

Comment: Thank you. JEditorPane does not have the possibility to do that by default. However, I could solve it creating a new action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve it creating a new action for `Shift + Enter` key combination:

```java
private static final String NEW_LINE = "new-line";

private static void initializeEditorPane(JEditorPane textArea) {
    HTMLEditorKit kit = new HTMLEditorKit();
    textArea.setEditorKit(kit);

    InputMap input = textArea.getInputMap();
    KeyStroke shiftEnter = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("shift ENTER");
    input.put(shiftEnter, NEW_LINE);

    ActionMap actions = textArea.getActionMap();
    actions.put(NEW_LINE, new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                kit.insertHTML((HTMLDocument)textArea.getDocument(), textArea.getCaretPosition(),
                        "<br>", 0,0, HTML.Tag.BR);
                textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getCaretPosition()); // This moves caret to next line
            } catch (BadLocationException | IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Nice one! Glad you got it sorted. :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment and your help. I have already accepted the answer. I hope also to see you in future posts.